# How do I add another value to the PDO insert statement, regardless of the array to be entered

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to PDO and I'm trying to redesign my system and add some new functions.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me, I got the first part myself, but since I have little experience with PDO, as I said, I just can't get any further.

As the heading suggests, there are a number of INSERT statements.

Entering the values works great!
But now another value has to be written and I don't know how the syntax should work.

Here is my previous code:

```
$player_tag = "#xyz";

$a_arr = [];
$b_arr = [];
$c_arr = [];

$a_arr[] =
    ["name" => $decoded_json['name'],
        "rank" => (int)$decoded_json['rank']];
$b_arr[] =
    ["name" => $decoded_json_2['name'],
        "rank" => (int)$decoded_json_2['rank']];
$c_arr[] =
    ["name" => $decoded_json_3['name'],
        "rank" => (int)$decoded_json_3['rank']];

$tables_to_insert = [];

if (!empty($a_arr)) $tables_to_insert[] = "a";
if (!empty($b_arr)) $tables_to_insert[] = "b";
if (!empty($c_arr)) $tables_to_insert[] = "c";

if (!empty($tables_to_insert)) {

    foreach ($tables_to_insert as $table) {

        $current_arr = ${$table . "_arr"};  // a_arr, b_arr, c_arr
        console_log($current_arr);
        $current_table = 'player_' . $table; // player_a, player_b, player_c 

        $names_arr = array_column($current_arr, 'name');
        $ranks_arr = array_column($current_arr, 'rank');

        $names = implode(", ", $names_arr);


        $place_holders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ranks_arr), '?'));

        $sth = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `" . $current_table . "` ($names) VALUES ($place_holders)");

        $sth->execute($ranks_arr);

    }
}
```

What should be added:

colum player_tag for all this tables

I try this, but it did not work.

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `" . $current_table . "` (player_tag, $names) VALUES ($player_tag, $place_holders)");

$sth->execute($ranks_arr);
```

Comment: what error you are receiving?

Comment: so you're basically just looking for `$names_arr[] = 'player_tag'; $ranks_arr[] = $player_tag;`?

Comment: Hi with PDO it's about splitting up the query and the values so it removes the risk of sql injection. When I did this I used a nice library called fluentPDO https://github.com/envms/fluentpdo  which made it all really easy you can use composer but I just copied the code and setup the include/require and it all just worked.

Comment: @YourComonSense - yes, I think about this, maybe it's the easiest solution!

I just thought there might be a possibility without passing the tag in the same array

Thanks, I will solve it as you said.

Comment: @Richard thanks for your tip! I'll look at it right away